# Using 'a bit of water / wine ... ' vs 'a drop of water / wine' to describe a small quantity of liquid

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Is it correct to say, "a bit of water" or should it be "a drop of water"?

More generally, can the word "bit" be used to describe a small quantity of a liquid or can it only be used for solids?

Comment: “A drop of water” is ambiguous: it can be used abstractly to refer to just a bit of water, somewhat old-fashionedly (“I wonder if I might trouble you for a drop of water, my good lady?”); or it can be literal and refer to one single drop of water, which is certainly a very small bit.

Comment: "A bit of water" is even more ambiguous, as it could mean a drop, or a gallon.  One might be  mixing concrete in a 25 gallon "tub", and adding "a bit of water" might mean adding a half gallon or a gallon.

Comment: @HotLicks _A bit_ is ambiguous as to exactly how much constitutes that bit; but it’s at least only got one meaning (‘a small amount as compared to something seen as the whole or total’), which is inherently imprecise. _Drop_ is ambiguous in that you can’t even count on it being consistently precise or imprecise.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Actually, a "drop" is precisely 1/20th of a milliliter of water.

Comment: NOUN [a + ~ + of + uncountable noun] a small quantity of something:
_I'd like a bit of wine to go with this_.
https://www.wordreference.com/definition/bit

Comment: A bit basic. I’d drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [bit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bit) is used informally to refer to:

> - *a small piece or amount of something:* (Cambridge Dict.)
>
>   - Would you like a bit of chocolate?
>       The glass smashed into little bits.
>       There were bits of paper all over the floor.
>       She tries to do a bit of exercise every day.
>       I don't understand this bit.

It is also used informally to refer to a small amount of a liquid:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20bit%20of%20water%2Ca%20bit%20of%20whiskey%2Ca%20bit%20of%20beer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20bit%20of%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bit%20of%20whiskey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bit%20of%20beer%3B%2Cc0): a bit of water, beer,  whiskey.

- Some more whiskey? Just a little bit please.

A *drop* may figuratively convey the same meaning as *a small amount* but *a bit or a little bit*  are probably more common expressions with that respect.

Comment: But usage is idiosyncratic. You would rarely ask directly 'Have you a bit of whisk[e]y, please?';  'Have you a drop of whisk[e]y, please?' is far more normal.

Comment: Naa ... it's just a bit in the ocean.

Comment: The point Edwin was making is that *drop* and *a bit* are not always interchangeable. It's not *only*  a question of which term is more commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

Both the phrases are used commonly.

For ex: *I am in such a pathetic state that even a drop of water will prove to be of some use*.

*I need a little bit of water to quench my thirst.*

If you look at the synonyms for 'bit', you'll find 'piece' and 'segment' which are commonly used for solids.

We also use 'bit' in phrases like: 'a bit of sunshine', 'a bit of luck' etc.(for intangible ideas)

'A drop' is way smaller in quantity than 'a bit'. So check the context and use the most appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

*More generally, can the word "bit" ...only be used for solids?*

Certainly not. Using `bit` or `little bit` with liquids is perfectly normal.

`Drop` is acceptable too, but you should note that more often than not, `drop` is used in negative sentences. As in:

> I stopped drinking. I haven't tasted a drop of whiskey in six months.

In positive sentences, `bit` is more natural. `Drop` sounds old-fashioned, like Janus noted, or humouous.

---

PS - `Bit` can also be used with gases. See [Google books results](https://www.google.com/search?q=a%20bit%20of%20air&oq=a%20bit%20of%20air&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2502j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22a%20bit%20of%20air%22&tbm=bks) for 'a bit of air'

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for 'a drop of juice' people know you don't literally mean a drop, you mean a small amount. Old fashioned or not, when referring to  a small amount of liquid it sounds far better to ask for a drop or a small amount or a specific amount like a glass of or a pint of than a bit of.

Whilst it is perfectly fine to refer to feeling a little bit cold or asking for a bit of peace and quiet, I think you really need to think about what you are saying and the context. I wouldn't ask for a bit of fruit I would ask for a small amount, a piece of or portion.

Use words like piece of when referring to some selotape instead of bit of, its just lazy. Using the word bit is like using the word said - there are far better words to be used that make your sentences sound better. If you look in the Cambridge English Dictionary, not one of their examples of their usage of the word bit refers to an amount of liquid!

Also I would personally never ask for a bit of flour I would ask for some flour.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have the answer. People say you can't have a bit of liquid, only a drop. But if you ask for a bit of water you are saying you want an amount of water. Measurements typically used for liquids do not always have to be used for liquid. You could have 100ml flour. So asking for a bit of flour could refer to wanting 10ml from my 100ml jug, just as asking for a bit of water could be 10ml out of 100ml. So as measurements are not fluids you can have a bit of them. Ergo, you can have a bit of liquid.